# Knockout.js - Configuring Bindings after loading model via Ajax

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm building a large page with 10 different forms on it- each form will be its own model, with a master model pulling them all in.

First:

```
var masterPageModel = new PageViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(masterPageModel);
```

Which references pageViewModel.js::

```
// section-specific models
this.selectedCoverage = new SelectedCoverage();
// continue with other sub-models...
```

Which references selectedCoverage.js (and others) like so:

```
this.tier_chosen = ko.observable("Individual + Family");
this.subscriber_dob = ko.observable('January 15, 1970');
this.subscriber_age = ko.observable(43);
```

I now realize I need to pre-populate the data in those models.  So, I started down this path:

```
var self = this;
$.getJSON("./load.php",{},function(data){
    self.selectedCoverage = new SelectedCoverage(data);
});
```

Now, selectedCoverage.js looks like:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
```

However, my form no longer works as intended.  Specifically, the "with: [model]" is no longer seeing the relevant model.

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedCoverage" >
```

The page no longer sees this model, like it did before, and therefore, the whole section is  hidden.

I also tried to reference it via $root, but still had no luck.

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedCoverage" >
```

How can I make sure the appliedBindings know where the ajax-acquired models are?

Thanks.

---

**Update**
I did try to make those initial values observable, but no joy:

```
// *** section-specific models
self.selectedCoverage = ko.observable();
$.getJSON("./load.php",{},function(data){
    self.selectedCoverage = new SelectedCoverage(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the rest of the code, mainly how and when you bind your view model to the DOM, but I think it may be because `selectedCoverage` (and `contactInformation` by the way) are not observable objects. What you should do is probably this:

```
self.selectedCoverage = ko.observable();
self.contactInformation = ko.observable();

$.getJSON("./load.php",{},function(data){
    self.selectedCoverage(new SelectedCoverage(data));
    self.contactInformation(new ContactInformation(data));
});
```

Comment: it's not self.selectedCoverage = new SelectedCoverage(data) but self.selectedCoverage(new SelectedCoverage(data));